# php-How to have a button submit and send to page

Tags: php, button

I'm trying to make a button that submits order input to a database and then takes the user to the home page on my site, but I don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="window.location.href='PurimHome.html'"> Place Order</button>
```

This button sends the info to the db but it doesn't go to the home page.
Here is more of the code:(I'm using bootstrap)

```
      <form class="form-horizontal"  action=""  method="post">

      <label  class="col-sm-2" >Credit Card Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="creditnum" name="creditnum" placeholder="Credit Card Number"  >
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
<label  class="col-sm-2" >Expiration Date</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="date"  class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Expiration Date" >
</div>
 </div>
     <div class="form-group">
  <label  class="col-sm-2" >Security Code</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Three Digit Code" >
 </div>
  </div>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" id="contact" value="Phone">   Contact Me by Phone<br>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="window.location.href='PurimHome.html'"> Place Order</button>


      </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: `<form action="somepage.php">...<input type="submit></form>`

Comment: Post your whole code so I can implement it the correct way!

Comment: I think this question holds more than we've been left to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to relocate to a different site after you submit.. then maybe you should place in your controller something like..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//do stuff if needed
     header('Location: url');
}
```

so that after you submit the form it will then redirect you to antoher location of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.  should add to the button id="submit"  ?

Comment: I added name="submit" and id="submit" to the button and it Works. Thank you.

Comment: This won't work if some content is already sent. Please mention that this should be on the __very__ top

Comment: Can you please explain more .